# how to find all the elements with any of these attributes?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

have a look at these tags and their attributes:
[link](https://www.coingecko.com/en/exchanges?page=4)

```
</tr> <tr data-has-trading-incentive="false" data-is-centralized="true">

</tr> <tr data-has-trading-incentive="false" data-is-centralized="true">   </tr> <tr data-is-centralized="true">

</tr> <tr data-has-trading-incentive="true">

</tr> <tr data-has-trading-incentive="false" data-is-centralized="false"> </tr> <tr data-has-trading-incentive="false">
```

I want to find all the elements with the tag "tr" and attributes like any of the following using Beautifulsoup in python.

here is what I am doing

```
soup.findAll("tr",attrs={re.compile("(data\-is\-centralized|data\-has\-trading-incentive)"):re.compile("(true|false)")})
```

but this doesn't return any value. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use css OR syntax to match on either attribute

```
soup.select('[data-has-trading-incentive], [data-is-centralized]')
```

Comment: However, won't this also return elements which are non <tr>?

Comment: Only tr have these attributes. You could prefix with tr e..g `tr[data-has-trading-incentive], tr[data-is-centralized]`  but it just slows the match slightly.

Comment: Its not necessay. The first condition is that it should have a "tr" tag

Comment: Okay got it @QHarr

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` accepts functions as well wherein the function takes each `element` as its attribute by default.

Try this:

```
def findFilter(element):
    if element.name == "tr":
        if any(attr in list(element.attrs.values()) for attr in ['data-has-trading-incentive','data-is-centralized']):
            return True
    return False


filteredElements = soup.find_all(findFilter)
```

Comment: What's elm.attrs?

Comment: My bad. Edited it.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks!